# log4c documentation

Tags: c, log4cxx

gcc 4.4.3 c89

I am just getting started with log4c. However, there is very little documentation out there for how to get started with it.

I am wondering does anyone know of any tutorials, articles on how to get started?

Comment: Did you find any tutorial mate??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since log4c and log4net are both ports of log4j, may be you can use log4j/log4net documentation. Since it is a port, the configuration and API should be the same

log4net documentation:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 6):

If you unpack the tar ball from the project page at http://log4c.sourceforge.net/ there is a doc directory containing examples etc.

Also there is the developer's guide at http://www.slideshare.net/gzm55/log4-c-developers-guide-presentation.