# how to read logfile using log4c and print it

Tags: c, log4c

I have used log4c to write some logs to file, then I want to read the file,and show the logs at the terminal, but I can't find the API，If someone can help solve the problem,I will be very appreciated!!!

Comment: Please see [log4c documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574464/log4c-documentation)

Comment: thank you, but I really can't find what I need

Comment: the log4c seem not to support this operation,I have to write this operation by myself